# A FileSet package/class wanted for Java

Tags: java

Can anyone suggest a FileSet package/class in Java. By FileSet I mean a collection of files and directories together with regex-powered inclusion and exclusion rules (similar to Apache Ant). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of [`File#listFiles()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29) wherein you pass a [`FileFilter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) or [`FilenameFilter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) where in turn you can specify the desired pattern in the `accept()` method.

E.g.

```
File[] txtFiles = file.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.endsWith(".txt"); // You can use String#matches() as well.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Apache Commons IO [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) may be what you want. It has the capability to identify files with an optional filename filter that you can implement yourself.

See the doc for [listFiles()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles%28java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter%29) or [iterateFiles()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#iterateFiles%28java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter%29) for more info.